# .NET remoting - how to determine if there is still a reference to a remoted object in a neighbouring AppDomain?

Tags: .net, remoting

I've got an application which uses .NET Remoting to load plugins in another AppDomain (within the same process). This is done because plugins have to be unloadable.

Every now and then I get the exception in the main appdomain that a remoted object (inherited from `MarshalByRefObject`) in the plugin appdomain has been garbage collected. Since I control the code both for the plugins and the app itself, I can modify code on both sides in search for a solution.

The first idea was to provide an infinite lease for these objects. This works, but is only viable for a few global objects which will always be there. Other objects can become pretty memory-heavy, and I actually **want** to garbage collect them - when the primary appdomain is done with them, of course.

One possible solution is to implement `IDisposable` and switch to returning an expired lease for disposed objects. However that requires that I diligently `Dispose()` all the instances of these objects that I ever use. Quite a bit of code to go over and fix.

So I was wondering if there is some other way? I tried implementing a Finalizer, but that only seems to run on the remote appdomain, no matter whether the object was marshalled by value or reference. Is there any way to detect that a local wrapper is about to be garbage collected and then somehow mark the remote object as "free for garbage collection"?